# AMD driver instalation breaks appimages

Tags: drivers, gpu, appimage

So I am using blender and need the amd-pro driver for gpu compute, provided by amd, installation goes just fine, but after the reboot I can not open appimages anymore.

Is there a way to get appimages to work again?

Comment: All appimages or just a particular one?

Comment: I don't know, I only have one, the one from this github page: https://github.com/prusa3d/PrusaSlicer/releases

however I need to use another one from freecad, however their download site is down for the moment.